# jquery checkbox selcetion

Tags: php, jquery

Please refer the url

http://jsfiddle.net/fnvXT/

Here while selecting the check box the corresponding row is selected. I want to change that as

only one will be highlighted at a time.

If i select check box 2 then the check box 2 will be checked and this row only be highlighted and remaining check box should unchecked and remove the highlighting.

How do i change this. Please do the needful. Thanks

Comment: Why cant you use Radio buttons instead? http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm

Comment: Consider using `.each()` , when the user clicks a checkbox , use the .each loop to un-check all the others.

Comment: What  it should displaye when we click on 1,2,3,2 ?
Or 1,2,3,3,2,3,1,1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the following to the click handler:

```
$('input.high').not(this).attr('checked', null).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#fff');
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/fnvXT/6/

Comment: For small lists this will work, however, there will be a performance hit looping through all the "input.high" objects plus checking to see if the current one is not "this" one.  If your list increases or is dynamic, you might want to consider a local variable instead.

Comment: @ChrisGessler You're absolutely right, but one step at a time :-)

Comment: @TJ. - nice oneliner though :)

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go...

```
var currentRow;

$('.high').live('click', function(event) {
    if(currentRow) currentRow.css("background-color", "white");
    currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    currentRow.css("background-color", "orange");                

     });
```

Comment: Please refer the fiddle now http://jsfiddle.net/fnvXT/4/ Here the high light is not removed for other radio buttons. How to remove this. Selected row only should highlighted.

Comment: Ahhh... the highlighted ROW needs to change.  Gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `.live()` function it has been deprecated. Use `.on()` or `.delegate()` instead. Here is a simple solution to your problem

```
 $('.high').on('click', function(event) {          
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
             // if checked, reset all colors to white
             $("tr").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
             // find its parent row and change its color
             $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", "#FFCC00");
        } else {
            // you only need to change its parent row in this case
            $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
        }           

});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/fnvXT/13/)

<sub>P.s. I have omitted the alternate row style in the row, to make things much simpler</sub>